# How to override Spree checkout forms and step flows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I'm using spree 2.0.0 in my application. I just want to know how i can edit spree checkout or how I can completely remove / disable any "Step" during Spree checkout process.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [Documentation](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/checkout.html) says, you can use `remove_checkout_step` helper method (which is also much clearer than redefining whole checkout process), for example:

```
Spree::Order.class_eval do
  # ...
  remove_checkout_step :delivery
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Hi Marek. Thanks for your solution its great and definitely it is stated in the spree documentation. Actually i tried it before but when i proceed after filling address fields it redirects me to cart page even i have things already added to cart. It may be application speciic but your answer is definitely is a solution.

Answer (score 6):

I just found the solution. Here it is.

```
Step 1:Create app/models/order_decorator.rb file

Step 2: Copy following code in your order_decorator.rb 

Spree::Order.class_eval do
  checkout_flow do
    go_to_state :address
    #go_to_state :delivery
    go_to_state :payment, if: ->(order) {
      order.update_totals
      order.payment_required?
    }
    go_to_state :confirm, if: ->(order) { order.confirmation_required? }
    go_to_state :complete, if: ->(order) {
      (order.payment_required? && order.has_unprocessed_payments?) || !order.payment_required?
    }
    remove_transition from: :delivery, to: :confirm
  end
end
```

Example: if you want to remove delivery state just comment it out.You can comment out any step.

You can find more info in the [documentation](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/checkout.html#the-checkout-flow-dsl).

Answer (score 4):

Default checkout Steps in Spree

1. Address
2. Delivery
3. Payment
4. Confirm

Spree allows you to modify checkout process to add or remove steps by using respective helpers.

- insert_checkout_step
- remove_checkout_step

In your case you should go with remove_checkout_step(to remove checkout step) 
The remove_checkout_step will remove just one checkout step at a time:

- remove_checkout_step :address
- remove_checkout_step :delivery

Comment: Nice explanation. Very helpful.